# What's the equivalent of auth.getIdTokenClient() on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, rest, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I need to query a token from a GCP function, for that, I want to do what the js function `GoogleAuth<JSONClient>.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience)` does but on Android.

Right now I'm using this code to generate an auth token:

```
GoogleCredentials
                .fromStream(
                    app.assets.open("my_config_file.json")
                )
                .createScoped(
                    listOf(
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
                    )
                )
```

But the token generated is a *ya29.c.*, wherewith the getIdToken I get a valid token.

How can I get a valid token as getIdToken on my Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java based applications you have the [google-auth-library-java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java). Looking in the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/index.html) for this library you have the [IdTokenCredentials.Builder](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/com/google/auth/oauth2/IdTokenCredentials.Builder.html) and [IdTokenCredentials](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/com/google/auth/oauth2/IdTokenCredentials.html) classes.

Also you have an example use case:

```java
 String credPath = "/path/to/svc_account.json";
 String targetAudience = "https://example.com";
 // For Application Default Credentials (as ServiceAccountCredentials)
 // export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/svc.json
 GoogleCredentials adcCreds = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
 if (!adcCreds instanceof IdTokenProvider) {
   // handle error message
 }

 IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential = IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
     .setIdTokenProvider(adcCreds)
     .setTargetAudience(targetAudience).build();

 // Use the IdTokenCredential in an authorized transport
 GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl("https://example.com");
 HttpCredentialsAdapter adapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(tokenCredential);
 HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
 HttpRequest request = transport.createRequestFactory(adapter).buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
 HttpResponse response = request.execute();

 // Print the token, expiration and the audience
 System.out.println(tokenCredential.getIdToken().getTokenValue());
 System.out.println(tokenCredential.getIdToken().getJsonWebSignature().getPayload().getAudienceAsList());
 System.out.println(tokenCredential.getIdToken().getJsonWebSignature().getPayload().getExpirationTimeSeconds());
```

###### Documentation:

- [Github repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 with the Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#gae-id)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed thanks you !
How do you export the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ? Directly on the computer ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for Android development, but that seems the way to go.